# How to restrict modification to selected properties of an entity while persisting?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

Let's suppose I have an entity class and a generic FormType corresponding to the entity

```
class Entry {
    protected $start_time;
    protected $end_time;
    protected $confirmed; // Boolean

    // ... Other fields and getters and setters
}
```

On the CRUD of this entity, I don't want to allow any modification on `start_time` or `end_time` if the entity has been confirmed or in the above case when `$confirmed === true`

On the twig file, I disable the fields I want to restrict, like the following:

```
{% if entity.approved == true %}
    {{ form_row(entity.start_time), { 'attr' : { 'disabled' : 'disabled' } }) }}
{% endif %}
{# Sameway for another field #}
```

Now the problem is that this is a front end resolution which can be tampered very easily using web developer tools in web browsers now. But regardless what I am trying to achieve is not have those two fields changed once the entity in confirmed.

So, one way I tried was after the form was submitted, I check if the entity was confirmed and if it was was, I fetch the earlier state of the entity and set the value of the new one (which is about to be persisted) with the values from old one.

On Controller:

```
$confirmed = $entity->getConfirmed();
$form->handleRequest($request);

if($form->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
    // The form was submitted
    if($confirmed === true) { // if the entity was confirmed previously
        $oldEntity = $em->getRepository('...')->find($entity->getId());
        $entity->setStartTime($oldEntity->getStartTime());
        $entity->setEndTime($oldEntity->getEndTime());
    }
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
}
```

The problem here was `$oldEntity` was exactly same as `$entity`. My guess is doctrine picked up that it already has the entity that is being asked and just returned me with the same object. Anyways, my attempt to solve this problem failed.

Any idea how to restrict/revert changes on selected properties while allowing changes on rest of the properties of the entity?

> *Update:*

Modifying the form type to disable the field is not an option because I only want them to be read-only/disabled only if entity is confirmed and rest of time I want the form to be as it is.

Comment: Note: Instead of `if($confirmed === true)`, you should instead use: `if($confirmed)` since it is a boolean. Same as in your twig: `{% if entity.approved == true %}` change to `{% if entity.approved %}`.

Comment: @AlvinBunk, You can assume it to be boolean but you cannot be assured of that. That is why it is done that way.

Answer (score 1):

You must add attribute `'disabled' => true` in form builder, not only in twig.

> If you don't want a user to modify the value of a field, you can set the disabled option to true. Any submitted value will be ignored.

Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#disabled

If you wish modify dynamically, use form events, example:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $entity = $event->getData();

    // if confirmed, disable start_time field
     if ($entity->getConfirmed()) {
        $config = $form->get('start_time')->getConfig();
        $options = $config->getOptions();

        // set disabled option to true
        $options['disabled'] = true;
        // replace origin field
        $form->add(
            'start_time',
            $config->getType()->getName(),
            $options
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Yea but you can easily change that with web developer tools in browser.

Comment: @TheDrot, no. Symfony ignore this fields. Read quoted text - `Any submitted value will be ignored.`

Comment: Ah, ok if it ignores even submitted fields then yea it's fine.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have mentioned this but I don't want to modify the form or creating new form type (just for this specific case). Please check the update as well.

Comment: @Starx, you tried to clone entity(or needed values from original entity) before handle request?

Comment: I tired that, but the real case is slightly different  where the restriction has to be made on CollectionType which as you can imagine forces me to clone all the collection (which can be n number). I am not sure if this is most efficient way to solve this though. But is an option.

Comment: @TheDrot, I tested this method just now, its does not ignore it. The changed value was persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem now @Starx, I didn't read very carefully at first, and your update helped.

Maybe you need to detach your Entity?

Check this link about (Entities in Session)[http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/entities-in-session.html]. Maybe storing the Entity in a session will work. Detaching as a separate Entity might work, and do a comparison on the detached Entity to your updated Entity.

Comment: Hmm.. I will check that. I also found a way to retrieve the original state of an entity from entity manager. Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37698751/295264)

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to solve this:

1. You can retrieve original data of the entity. It returns an array with old data of an entity which can be used to reset the data.

   ```
   if($form->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
       // The form was submitted
       if($confirmed === true) { // if the entity was confirmed previously
           $oldData = $em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($entity);
           $entity->setStartTime($oldData['start_time']);
           $entity->setEndTime($oldData['end_time']);
       }
       $em->persist($entity);
       $em->flush();
   }
   ```
2. Using Form Events

   The following is a Symfony 3 Solution, try maximkou's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37684212/295264) for Symfony 2.

   ```
   class EntityType extends AbstractType
   {
       public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
       {
           // ....
           // ....
           // Your form fields

           $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
       }


       public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event) {
           /** @var YourEntity $entity */
           $entity = $event->getData();
           $form = $event->getForm();

           if($entity instanceof YourEntity) {
               if ($entity->getTimesheetEntry()->getTimeApproved() === true) {
                   $config = $form->get('start_time')->getConfig();
                   $options = $config->getOptions();
                   $options['disabled'] = true;
                   $form->add('start_time', get_class($config->getType()->getInnerType()), $options);

                   $config = $form->get('end_time')->getConfig();
                   $options = $config->getOptions();
                   $options['disabled'] = true;
                   $form->add('end_time', get_class($config->getType()->getInnerType()), $options);
               }
           }

       }
   }
   ```

   [Source](http://blog.mrnepal.com/2016/06/08/how-to-restrict-modification-to-selected-properties-of-an-entity-while-persisting/)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code very well, but I notice after checking `confirmed === true` it doesn't appear you set the boolean back to false. However I presume you got what you needed working. If my comments have been helpful, please upvote them. Thanks!

Comment: @AlvinBunk, Why would I set the boolean back to false? I am just doing `some action` if they are true?

Comment: It has to do with supporting software and naming of variables. So you've called it "confirmed", which means the Entity has been confirmed. So some developer that looks at your code in future (not you) might think that once it gets confirmed, you set it back to "unconfirmed" (or false).   Like I said, I don't understand your code very well. But maybe once you've set it to "confirmed" (set to true), then you "never" set it back --> what a waste of a variable! There has to be a better way. This is just something for you to think about and only my opinion.

Comment: @AlvinBunk, You are not being able to see this within the scope of the question only. The code in the question and in the answers by me and others are very specific to the question's case only. But thank you for the pointer.